# Manage Apks on Linux - rename, icon version

Tags: 16.04, android

For windows there is excelent tool [apkshellext](https://github.com/kkguo/apkshellext) that lets you view apk's icon be default and also allows you to rename it in batch with apps version number

So simple with someone like me who has huge collection of apks

Any such software for linux

Comment: You can probably run that Windows program using Wine.

Comment: Nah! its not a standalone software, it shell extention for Windows Explorer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe [this](http://vaibhavpandey.com/apkstudio/) is what you are looking for.

Comment: It is an apk decomplier, but I am sure that it can be used to manipulate other propeties of apks too.

Comment: Not exactly what i am looking for but its only thing available for linux :(